# Combining HTML markup to display it from a controller

Tags: forms, 8

i am creating the custom html as follows and i am calling another form inside that form . But for the second form its only display as 'array' , and not displaying the entire form as expected .

in **module_name\src\Controller\MyController.php**

```
public function my_function($node) {  
  $arg1 = node_load($node);
// output node-information at the top of the page
  $result .= '<table>';
  $result .= html_create_tablerow(array('<b>nid:</b>', $arg1->nid->value));
  $result .= html_create_tablerow(array('<b>Name:</b>', $arg1->field_p_name[0]->value));
  $result .= html_create_tablerow(array('<b>Description:</b>', $arg1->field_p_description[0]->value));
  $result .= html_create_tablerow(array('<b>URL:</b> ', $arg1->field_p_url[0]->value));
  $result .= html_create_tablerow(array('<b>Proxy-ID:</b> ', $proxy_id));
  $result .= html_create_tablerow(array('<b>static html:</b> ', $htmlfolder_note));
  $result .= '</table>';


  #$param = gasf_get_parent_node($arg1->nid->value);
  $resultForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\module_name\Form\MyForm',$arg1);
  #print_r($resultForm);exit();
  $build = array(
       '#markup' => $result.$resultForm
      );
  return $build;
```

and in **module_name\Form\MyForm.php**

```
/**
 * General form for showing the main functionlities.
 */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state,$arg1 = NULL) {

  #if (!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])) {
    // two ways to transfer the nid
    $form_state['storage']['nid'] = $param->nid;
    $form['hidden'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $param->nid);

    /**
     * Find matching RPM files
     * field_p_rpservicename
     * sfeproxyenvironment
     * field_p_proxyinstance
    */
    $rpmGlob = get_proxy_id($param, 0);

    $rpms = glob($Config::getRpmFolder() . $rpmGlob . '-*.noarch.rpm');
    // sort RPM list in a natural human way
    natsort($rpms);
    $form_state['storage']['rpms'] = $rpms;

    // BEPI
    // TODO: query engines DB for this proxy and check which of the existing RPMs is installed.
    // Highlight that one in the available RPM list
    foreach ($rpms as $key => $value ) {
      $rpms[$key] = preg_replace('#' . $Config::getRpmFolder() . '#', '', $value);
      $rpms[$key] = preg_replace('#.noarch.rpm#', '', $rpms[$key]);
      $rpms[$key] = $rpms[$key] . ' ' . date('F d Y H:i:s.', filemtime($value));
    }

    # check if static folder for node 1 exists but current node does not
    # in that case, offer to copy the master node's static html content
    # to a new folder for the current node
    if ($param->field_p_proxyinstance[0]['value'] > 1) {
      $rpmGlob_master = get_proxy_id($param,1);
      if ((file_exists($Config::getStaticHtml() . $rpmGlob_master)) && (! file_exists($Config::getStaticHtml() . $rpmGlob))) {
        $form['submit_copy_statichtml_from_parent'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Copy static HTML from master node'),
          '#validate' => array('copy_statichtml_fom_master_node'),
        );
      }
    }


    $form['rpms'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Available RPM files'),
      '#options' => $rpms,
      '#description' => t(
        'If you want to deploy a present rpm file, or you want to delete one,
        choose it from above list.'
      ),
    );



    /* Display result for tasks. Will only show up if there is
     something to show.
    */
    $form['result'] = array(
        '#type' => $form_state['storage']['result']=='' ? 'hidden' : 'item',
        '#title' => t('Result'),
        '#value' => '<pre>' .  $form_state['storage']['result'] . '</pre>',
    );

    $form['submit_create_rpm'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Create RPM file'),
        '#validate' => array('_rpmcreate_preview'),
    );

    $form['submit_delete_rpm'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Delete RPM file'),
        '#validate' => array('_rpmdelete_preview'),
    );

    $form['submit_deploy'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Deploy'),
        '#validate' => array('_deploy_preview'),
    );

    $form['submit_decommission'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Decommission'),
        '#validate' => array('_decommission_preview'),
    );

    $form['submit_migrate'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Migrate'),
        '#validate' => array('_migrate_preview'),
    );

    $form['submit_showlog'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Show deployment log'),
        '#validate' => array('_showlog_preview'),
    );

    return $form;
}
```

Here the table thats created via html markup is displaying . But next to that its only shows `'Array'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the table markup and the form render array:

```
  $resultForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\module_name\Form\MyForm',$arg1);
  $build = [
    'table' => ['#markup' => $result],
    'form' => $resultForm,
  ];
  return $build;
```

By putting the table html in markup it becomes a render element. As the result of formBuilder() already is a render array, you can put those two together in a combined render array.