# Creating a route with a form and some content

Tags: forms, routes, page-controller

i have created a route with a form:

```
    amu_404_redirect_import.admin:
      path: '/admin/config/amu_404_redirect_import/upload'
      defaults:
        _form: '\Drupal\amu_404_redirect_import\Form\Amu404RedirectImportForm'
\Amu404RedirectImportController::content'
        _title: '404 redirect Import'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'administrer AMU 404 redirection import'
```

if now i am creating a controller to display some content to the same page , the form is not displayed anymore

```
amu_404_redirect_import.admin:
  path: '/admin/config/amu_404_redirect_import/upload'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\amu_404_redirect_import\Form\Amu404RedirectImportForm'
    _controller: '\Drupal\amu_404_redirect_import\Controller\Amu404RedirectImportController::content'
    _title: '404 redirect Import'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administrer AMU 404 redirection import'
```

how could i have both content displayed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it mentioned  in @Hudri answer it's not possible to define `_form` and a `_controller` in the same route.
I think the solution for your use case is to define only route for the controller and embed the form inside it, like the following:

```
amu_404_redirect_import.admin:
  path: '/admin/config/amu_404_redirect_import/upload'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\amu_404_redirect_import\Controller\Amu404RedirectImportController::content'
    _title: '404 redirect Import'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administrer AMU 404 redirection import'
```

and your controller should be something like:

```
namespace Drupal\ amu_404_redirect_import\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

class Amu404RedirectImportController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {
    $myForm = $this->formBuilder()
      ->getForm('Drupal\d8_api_exp\Form\Amu404RedirectImportForm');
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $myFormHtml = $renderer->render($myForm);
    // Add other markups here ....
    return [
      '#markup' => Markup::create("
                {$myFormHtml}
            "),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but don't render early, the form build can be nested inside of the build array the controller returns with the other content.

Comment: @4k4  could u precise how to do so?

Comment: @Matoeil, see for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202423/47547

Answer (score 3):

As [doc](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes) states

> defaults (required): Defines the default properties of a route.
>   Provide **one** of the following to specify how the output is generated:
>
> _controller
>   _form
>   _entity_view
>   _entity_list
>   _entity_form
>   _route

you can't list a `_form` **and** a `_controller` in the same `routing.yml` entry, only one of those keys is allowed. Either append that content via form API to your form, or render the form manually in your controller.